# Hardness vs Abrasion

Tags: material-science, diamond

Is it true that things that are hard, such as diamonds, wear out more slowly? Does abrasion depend on the hardness of the material? If so, why can diamonds in alluvial deposits survive for thousands of years? Does that mean they wear out so slowly that you hardly notice it? If I had a diamond and was rubbing it with a metal object all the time, how long would it take me to drill a visible cavity?

Answer (score 0):

Hardness yields resistance to abrasion. Because diamond is so hard, it abrades everything else it rubs against- except another diamond. You would have to tumble together a bucket of diamonds to get them to become abraded.

Note that it is possible to abrade a diamond with a soft metal grinding wheel that has diamond grit embedded in it. The diamond cuts the diamond, and the soft metal wears away, exposing fresh diamond grit. So, your question about rubbing a diamond with a piece of metal to drill a hole in the diamond- the answer is the metal will not drill a hole in the diamond unless it has diamond grit embedded in it.